# Assigning specific probability (e.g., 75%) that an item will appear using arrays to ensure exact percentage each trial

Tags: python, psychopy

I am creating an oddball paradigm for an infant EEG study. The experiment shows a 7 minute clip of fantasia. During the video every 6-10 seconds a pair of vibrations are sent out (triggered by an auditory beep sound) with an ISI of 700ms between them and a duration of 100ms for each vibration. For the oddball experiment we’d like to set an expectation of paired stimulation by having x amount of pairs appear first (e.g., 5) and then onwards have paired stimulation occur x% of time (75% chance) whilst 25% only a single vibration occurs.

So below I created a function that each time stimulus is presented a random roll between 0-100 happens and for the oddball stimulus to happen the number has to be > 75. This sort of works but it is not optimal because by chance I might get less or more than 25% oddball appearances within the 7-minute trial.

```
#we want to present the tone every
#6 - 10 seconds for the duration of the trial
#if the sound is not currently playing
if not tactors1.playing and not tactors1.waiting:
# pick how long we will wait for
 tactors1ISI = randint(6, 10)
 print(‘tactorISI’, tactors1ISI)
 tactors1ISIs.append(tactors1ISI)
 tactors1Onset = t +tactors1ISI
 #we are waiting for the sound to play
 tactors1.waiting = True
 pulse_started_tactors1 = False
 port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31, 0x4c, 0x44])
 port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32, 0x52, 0x44])
 port_trigger_eeg.write([0x00])
 dice_roll = random.randint(0,100)


if not tactors1.playing and tactors1.waiting:
 if t >= tactors1Onset:
 print(‘playing 1st tactor’)
    first_tactor_played = False
    tactors1.play()
    tactors1_on_times +=1
    tactors1Onsets.append(t)
    tactors1.playing = True
    tactors1.waiting = False
    first_tactor_start_time = core.getTime() # Gets a timestamp of the start of the first vibration       
    port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x45])
    port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x45])
    first_tactor_played = True
    print("the dice roll was", dice_roll)

if tactors1.playing:
 if t >= tactors1Onset + tactors1.secs:
  tactors1.stop()
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x44])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x44])
  tactors1.playing = False
  first_tactor_played = True
  first_tactor_stop_time = core.getTime()

if tactors1.playing == True and not pulse_started_tactors1:
 port_trigger_eeg.write([0x01])
 pulse_start_time_tactors1 = globalClock.getTime()
 pulse_started_tactors1 = True

print("tactor1 has played",tactors1_on_times,"times.")
if pulse_started_tactors1 and not pulse_ended_tactors1:
 if globalClock.getTime() - pulse_start_time_tactors1 >= 0.1:
 port_trigger_eeg.write([0x00])
 port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x44])
 port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x44])
 pulse_ended_tactors1 = True

#2nd vibration

if not tactors2.playing and not tactors2.waiting:
 if first_tactor_played == True:
 # pick how long we will wait for
  tactors2ISI = 0.7
  print(‘tactor2ISI’, tactors2ISI)
  tactors2ISIs.append(tactors2ISI)
  tactors2Onset = t +tactors2ISI
  #we are waiting for the sound to play
  tactors2.waiting = True
  pulse_started_tactors1 = False
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31, 0x4c, 0x44])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32, 0x52, 0x44])

if not tactors2.playing and tactors2.waiting:
 if first_tactor_played == True and tactors1_on_times <=5:
  if t >= tactors2Onset:
  print(‘playing 2nd tactor’)
  tactors2.play()
  tactors2Onsets.append(t)
  tactors2.playing = True
  tactors2.waiting = False
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x45])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x45])
  print("tactor2 has played ",tactors2_on_times,“times.”)

if not tactors2.playing and tactors2.waiting:
 if first_tactor_played == True and tactors1_on_times >5:
  if dice_roll <= 75 and t >= tactors2Onset:
  print(‘playing 2nd tactor’)
  tactors2.play()
  tactors2_on_times +=1
  tactors2Onsets.append(t)
  tactors2.playing = True
  tactors2.waiting = False
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x45])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x45])
  first_tactor_played = True


if tactors2.playing:
 if t >= tactors2Onset + tactors2.secs:
  if first_tactor_played == True:
  tactors2.stop()
  tactors2.playing = False
  first_tactor_played = False
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31, 0x4c, 0x44])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32, 0x52, 0x44])

if tactors2.playing == True and not pulse_started_tactors2:
 port_trigger_eeg.write([0x02])
 pulse_start_time_tactors2 = globalClock.getTime()
 pulse_started_tactors2 = True
 print(“tactor2 has played”,tactors2_on_times,“times.”)

if pulse_started_tactors2 and not pulse_ended_tactors2:
 if globalClock.getTime() - pulse_start_time_tactors2 >= 0.1:
  port_trigger_eeg.write([0x00])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x31,0x44])
  port_tactors.write([0x1b, 0x54, 0x32,0x44])
  pulse_ended_tactors2 = True
```

The way to fix this is to create upon the start of the experiment a randomized array of tactors1ISIs. Following this, another array based on the array above should ensure that although presentation of single or paired stimulation should be randomised, overall exactly 75% of stimuli presented will be pairs and that the remaining 25% are oddball stimuli within the 7 minute window of the trial… Way more complicated than I can do… Any ideas/help on how to do this would be super appreciated

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your goal is. If you want to have exactly 75%/25%, then it's not a *probability* of 75%/25%. If you want exactly 75%/25%, then you should explicitly *select* this amount. If you want a probability of 75%/25%, then you should not expect exactly 75%/25%.

Comment: That is true then its not a probability. I guess I meant randomised presentation of single or pair vibrations however in total paired stimulation should consist of 75% of all vibrations and 25% should be single vibration within a 7 minute window

Comment: That makes sense. Please [edit] your post to fix the code formatting (e.g. indentation, quotes) and if possible reduce the code to the relevant parts or even just a representative example, though. See the [mcve] help page for detauls.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advice on formatting. Any contribution towards solving this problem would be appreciated